# Error with calculator type program in python

Tags: python

```
numbers=[]
while True:
    print('Input Number '+str(len(numbers)+1)+' (or nothing to close):')
    number=input()
    numbers=numbers+[number]
    if number=='':
        print('What do you want to do?')
        answer=input()
        break
        if answer==mean:
            mean
def mean():
    end_mean=reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers) / len(numbers)
    print(end_mean)
```

I am trying to make a calculator type program in python which allows you to enter a list of numbers and then select what you do with them. The script above is only the beginning but when i enter the numbers and type in 'mean' when it asks me what to do, it ends the script and shows nothing. I am new to python so please be forgiving as such in the answers.

Edit 3 -

After using answers below i have fixed the script to end up with this:

```
import functools
numbers=[]

def means():
    end_mean = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers) / len(numbers)
    print(end_mean)

def sum():
    end_sum = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers)
    print(end_sum)

def whatDo():
        print('Input Extra Numbers '+str(len(numbers)+1)+' (or nothing to close):')
        try:
            number= int(input())
            numbers.append(number)
        except:
            print('What do you want to do?')
            answer = input()
            if answer == "mean":
                means()

while True:
    print('Input Number '+str(len(numbers)+1)+' (or nothing to close):')
    try:
        number= int(input())
        numbers.append(number)
    except:
        print('What do you want to do?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == "mean":
            means()
            print('Do you want anything else?')
            reply=input()
            if reply=='no':
                break
            elif reply--'yes':
                whatDo()
        else:
            break
```

However i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/calculator.py", line 26, in <module>
    number= int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/calculator.py", line 37, in <module>
    elif reply--'yes':
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

after the 'Do you want anything else' and i enter 'yes'.

Comment: your `break` is before the `if` checking `if answer == 'mean':` (I added quotes) and `mean` should be `mean()` to call a function

Comment: What python version you are using? python2 or python3?

Comment: python 3 @AhsanulHaque

Comment: Remove the first `break`, as it never allow you to execute the later lines. More importantly, learn carefully how `break` works in a loop.

Comment: You did *not* fix everything we said: you still have that **break** ending your program before you can print anything.  In fact, you added another one; that second one may be what you want.

Comment: sorry @Prune just me being stupid.

Comment: I've been there enough times that they granted me honorary citizenship.  This is called "experience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will help you.

```
numbers=[]

def means():
    end_mean = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, numbers) / len(numbers)
    print(end_mean)

while True:
    print('Input Number '+str(len(numbers)+1)+' (or nothing to close):')
    try:
        number= int(input())
        numbers.append(number)
    except:
        print('What do you want to do?')
        answer = input()
        if answer == "mean":
            means()
        else:
            break
```

What have I changed from your Code?

- Added a `try-except` block. This is added so that it can handle the case when you passed `''` as input.
- cast input to `int` before passing to number, as you need `int` value to calculate mean, not `string` values.
- You are making a list from the input and then adding to the previous list, which is unnecessary and inefficient. I replace it with `numbers.append(number)`
- The unnecessary `break` statement removed. `break` is used to get out from the loops. As you use `break`, you will never see the later statements executed.

Answer (score 1):

First, you **break** before you get to the check.  Your check itself will also fail:

```
if answer==mean:
    mean
```

You've compared the answer (a string) to mean (a function object).  Try:

```
if answer == "mean":
    mean()
```

Also, I expect that you want to convert the input numbers from **string** to **int**:

```
if number=='':
    ....
else:
    numbers=numbers+[int(number)]
```

Comment: Whatever, this portion will never be executed because OP is returning unconditionally earlier.

Comment: Right; I mistakenly deleted that from the original post.  Fixed now.